# Sql Case Column 1 and Column same value then apply calculation

Tags: sql, case, inner-join

I would like apply calculation in CASE Statement, but the result is not I'm expected and I'm not sure how to apply the query to filter date(depend on month). What is the problem with my query?? Please help... Thank you

this is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.SERVICE_CODE, 
       CASE WHEN
           b.SERVICE_CODE IS NULL THEN a.AMT ELSE  SUM (a.AMT) - SUM(b.AMT) END AS TOTAL_AMT
       FROM Table a
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table b ON (a.SERVICE_CODE = b.SERVICE_CODE)
 WHERE  b.SERVICE_CODE >='3000' AND c.SERVICE_CODE >='3000'
```

Table a

```
Invoice_No               date          Service_code     Amt
001                     1/7/2014       6000             300
002                     1/8/2014       6003             700
003                     5/8/2014       6003             100
004                     10/8/2014      6005             1000
```

Table b

```
Credit_No                 date          Service_code     Amt
c100                     1/7/2014       6000             300
c200                     13/8/2014      6003             700
```

Desired output

```
Service_code              Total_Amt
6003                      100
6005                      1000
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide sample input and desired output?

Comment: Well - if duplicate result comes out with a `distinct`, then it is not actually duplicated but in fact different. You'll need to provide us with table content and desired output for anybody to be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

try like this

In `MYSQL`

```
select t1.SERVICE_CODE,(t1.amt- case when  c.amt is null then 0 else c.amt end) 
as AMT  from t1 c right outer join (select t.Invoice_No,SERVICE_CODE,
sum(amt) as amt from t group by SERVICE_CODE) as t1  
on c.SERVICE_CODE=t1.SERVICE_CODE 
inner join tablea a on a.invoice_no=t1.Invoice_No
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/890d3/1)

Comment: Can Table A be the main table?

Comment: @user3559600 MySQl or Sql Server

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
bcode, 
case 
    when ccode is null then bamt 
    else bamt - camt 
end as amt
from
(select service_code bcode, sum(amt) bamt
 from b
 where service_code >= 3000
 group by service_code) b
left join
(select service_code ccode, sum(amt) camt
 from c
 where service_code >= 3000
group by service_code) c on b.bcode = c.ccode
order by bcode
```

Going by sample data, table `b` may have values for `service_code` that table `c` may not. Therefore, use a left outer join to link `b` and `c`. Also, since `invoice_no` does not need to appear in the output, you do not need to join to `a` at all.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19128/12)

Comment: Thank you for reply.However I try to apply the code, the output still not I expected. It duplicate 28 times with same Invoice_no but different amount. Please Help.Thanks

Comment: Where do you get `invoice_no` from above query?

Comment: after I applied the query given from you. I noticed the amount is not correct. Therefore I added the Invoice_no to check it.

Comment: When you say not correct, can you please edit your question to include what is the error when you use my query? It matches the expected output based on your sample data, so you need to provide details on what's going wrong with the actual data. Also, please include the query you used to join with `invoice_no`.